# Invalid default value for user_id_id in django

Tags: python, mysql, django, foreign-key-relationship

I am new to django and I am creating my models but I am having trouble when trying to add a foreign key to another model. here's my models:

```
from django.db import models

class User(models.Model):
    user_id = models.CharField(max_length=10, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=30)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    phone = models.IntegerField()
    GPA = models.FloatField(max_length=5)
    Gender = models.CharField(max_length=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user_id


class Login(models.Model):
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,  default='00000')
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=30)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

When I type makemigrations I get this:

```
You are trying to change the nullable field 'user_id' on login to non-nullable without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows)
 2) Ignore for now, and let me handle existing rows with NULL myself (e.g. because you added a RunPython or RunSQL operation to handle NULL values in a previous data migration)
 3) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
Select an option:  3
```

So I added a default value but I am getting this error when I tried to migrate. I tried to change user_id from User to AutoField so I don't have to add any default value but it is still giving me this error. Plus I don't know why it says user_id_id at the end. Can anyone help me out with this?

```
    Running migrations:
      Rendering model states... DONE
      Applying login.0003_login_user_id...Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 64, in execute
        return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
      File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 112, in execute
        return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
      File "C:\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 226, in execute
        self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
      File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 42, in defaulterrorhandler
        raise errorvalue
      File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 223, in execute
        res = self._query(query)
      File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 379, in _query
        rowcount = self._do_query(q)
      File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 342, in _do_query
        db.query(q)
      File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 286, in query
        _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
    _mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1067, "Invalid default value for 'user_id_id'")

    The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 5.0.4\helpers\pycharm\django_manage.py", line 41, in <module>
        run_module(manage_file, None, '__main__', True)
      File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\runpy.py", line 182, in run_module
        return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name, mod_spec)
      File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
        mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
      File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
        exec(code, run_globals)
      File "C:/Users/Desktop/Project/TSL/mysite\manage.py", line 10, in <module>
        execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
      File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
        utility.execute()
      File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 345, in execute
        self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
      File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
        self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
      File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 399, in execute
        output = self.handle(*args, **options)
      File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 200, in handle
        executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
      File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 92, in migrate
        self._migrate_all_forwards(plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
      File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 121, in _migrate_all_forwards
        state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
      File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 198, in apply_migration
        state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
      File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 123, in apply
        operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
      File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py", line 62, in database_forwards
        field,
      File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\schema.py", line 50, in add_field
        super(DatabaseSchemaEditor, self).add_field(model, field)
      File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 396, in add_field
        self.execute(sql, params)
      File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 110, in execute
        cursor.execute(sql, params)
      File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 79, in execute
        return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
      File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 64, in execute
        return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
      File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 95, in __exit__
        six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
      File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\six.py", line 685, in reraise
        raise value.with_traceback(tb)
      File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 64, in execute
        return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
      File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 112, in execute
        return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
      File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 226, in execute
        self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
      File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 42, in defaulterrorhandler
        raise errorvalue
      File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 223, in execute
        res = self._query(query)
      File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 379, in _query
        rowcount = self._do_query(q)
      File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 342, in _do_query
        db.query(q)
      File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 286, in query
        _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
    django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1067, "Invalid default value for 'user_id_id'")

    Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: models.ForeignKey will append "_id" to the real column name in database, so you need to change your column name to 'user' instead of 'user_id'.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as mentioned in the comments, do NOT name the `ForeignKey` field `user_id`, but `user`. This will create a column called `user_id` in the db table and your model instance's `user` attribute will return a `User` instance while its auto-generated attribute `user_id` will return that user's id.

As for specifying a default value for a `ForeignKey`. If you do that on the model, make sure you provide an **existing** User. If you choose to provide a one-off default during `makemigrations` (if you select option 1), make sure to provide the primary key of an **existing** User. Alternatively, make sure there are no existing `Login` records in the db.

Answer (score 0):

django automatically creates a primary keys for all your models, and it manages it internally.

Unless you have a very specific reason, you do not want to be managing or fiddling with the primary key manually.

Now, the specific reason for your error is that once you changed the type of field from `CharField` to `AutoField`, it changed the type from a character to an integer - but then you are assigning it a default value of a string (character), which is causing error from your database.

My best advice for you is to start from scratch. You don't need the `Login` model at all, django comes with [authentication built-in](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/) and its own "user" model.

```
from django.db import models

# Renamed from User to MyUser,
# User is a built-in model that comes with django
# and is used when logging people into the system
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/

class MyUser(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField() # email field doesn't need max_length
    password = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=30) # this should be a CharField
    GPA = models.FloatField()
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1,
                              choices=(('M', 'Male',),
                                       ('F', 'Female',),
                                       ('X', 'Prefer not to disclose',)))
```

Comment: Is it the auth_user table that is django's user model? Can I add my own fields in it?

Comment: You can [extend it](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model) or [replace it completely](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model). I would recommend you go with the extending option, as its much simpler.

Comment: Thank you. You saved me a lot of time.